# why im getting a Method not found exception into production iis but not in my VS IIS Express?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

On my IIS Express everything works fine, but in production im getting an error. How can i solve that problem?

> Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler>
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'.
>
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
>   Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'. Source
>   Error:   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of
>   the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location
>   of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.   Stack Trace:  [MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler>
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'.]
>
>   CDW.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) in
>   L:\W\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:25
>
>   System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1
>   configurationCallback) +46
>   CDW.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in L:\W\Global.asax.cs:17
>   [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler>
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'.]
>
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +517
>
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +185
>
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
>
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +277
>
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +369 [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +111    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +714

Version Information:

- Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
- ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

Comment: Gonna take a shot in the dark and say not all your code made it to your published location?

Comment: Most likely you are missing a reference that in your OS is by default, or your production environment IIS is bad configured.

Comment: Use Microsoft's "Assembly Binding Log Viewer" (Fuslogvw.exe) to make sure that you don't have a missing assembly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved this by adding the following code in `webconfig`.

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: How did you find out that this binding caused the issue?